How to get the same letter size in the flutter
All settings of the letters above and below are the same.
However, as the contents of the letters change, the two sizes do not match each other.
Is there a way to solve this?
child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(height: 9,),
                  Text(
                    '              24.07.23 16:31',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 23,
                        fontFamily: "Interop",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '              24.10.15 16:01',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 23,
                        fontFamily: "Interop",

                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),


I tried to use a code like textScaleFactor to match the font size, but I couldn't solve it.

Check if there's any overlay or widget that's causing visual differences and remove leading whitespace in the strings that can affect the overall appearance.
Also try to give textAlign: TextAlign.left to both Texts, then test on different devices.

I prefer using FontFeature.tabularFigures()
style: TextStyle(
  fontFeatures: [ FontFeature.tabularFigures() ],
)

it uses tabular (monospace) figures.

Your texts do have the same font size:

The issue here is that the individual letters have different sizes - for example a 1 takes less horizontal space than a 0.
What you want to do is use the textAlign-property of the Text()-widget and set it to justify, like so:
Text(
    '24.10.15 16:01',
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 23,
        fontFamily: "Interop",
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
)

Also remove the leading whitespace from your text, as this has no impact.
This will yield a result similar to this:

For more information, see: How to justify text in a flutter column widget?
See also: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextAlign.html
An alternative approach would be to have each element of your string as a separate Text()-widget with an absolute width.

In normal fonts, as said in @rintu-banerjee answer, different letters has different widths and you can't have same width for all possible texts with same character count.
You need to use monospace fonts, monospaced fonts are some type of fonts which have same width for all characters and they used in IDEs, Command lines, ...
So you can find some monospaced fonts here in google fonts
You can use google fonts in flutter by these steps:

Add google_fonts package with flutter pub add google_fonts
Select your favorite font from google fonts website (filter fonts to Monospaced)
Use style from google_fonts in your text that you need to be monospaced, for example, if you want to use Roboto Mono font, you need to add style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono() to your text widget.

Example use:
child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Interop Font: '),
          Text('24.07.23 16:31' ,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Interop'),),
          Text('24.10.15 16:01' ,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Interop'),),
          SizedBox(height: 25),
          Text('Monospaced Fonts: '),
          Text('24.07.23 16:31', style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono()),
          Text('24.10.15 16:01', style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono()),
        ],
      ),

Result:


This requires to change the font, which is not wanted.
